# Debugging async await controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, async-await

I have implimented (what I think is) a simple async method in an ApiController like this:

```
public class CommentsController : ApiController
{
    private static readonly IList<CommentModel> Comments;

    static CommentsController()
    {
        // Note: Removed to abbreviate - populate comments manually here.
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof (IList<CommentModel>))]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAllComments()
    {
        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10000); // Breakpoint #1
            return Ok(Comments); // Breakpoint #2
        });

        // Breakpoint #3
    }
}
```

Note my breakpoints I have placed above.

What I expected to happen was at #1 when I hit continue, for the thread to wait but the flow to continue through #3 at this stage.

Then when the sleep was finished, to continue again and break at #2.

However during debugging it seems synchronous.

My question is firstly is this truly asynchronous, and how to I debug it to verify, or otherwise with unit tests?

Comment: Ps. I am hitting the api directly from the browser - perhaps that is the issue?

Answer (score 3):

> However during debugging it seems synchronous.

It's serial (not synchronous), because the `await` keyword is telling the method not to continue until that operation completed. The debugger will step through asynchronous methods in a serial way, which can make them appear synchronous; this is much more natural than having the debugger jump to unrelated code and then jump back again later.

> My question is firstly is this truly asynchronous

It's fake-asynchronous. In real-world code, you would never ever use `Task.Factory.StarNew`.

Furthermore, for ASP.NET apps, you should avoid sending work to the thread pool (`StartNew`, `Task.Run`, etc). Instead, you should call naturally-asynchronous APIs.

> how to I debug it to verify, or otherwise with unit tests?

You can call the method, verify that the task is not yet completed, and then await it. Note that to avoid race conditions, you should stub out whatever asynchronous service your controller is using.

Answer (score 2):

*Breakpoint 3* will never be hit, and it should not be.

The `Task` you start with `Task.Factory.StartNew` will run asynchronously.
But `await` basically waits for the `Task` to finish executing before continuing with the current method, and returns execution to the caller. So it adds a **continuation** to the given `Task`.
Since you are returning the result of the `Task`, *Breakpoint 3* will never execute.

If you want *Breakpoint 3* to execute after the `Task`, you basically have 2 options:

Either you add a continuation:

```
    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // Breakpoint #1
        return Ok(Comments); // Breakpoint #2
    }).ContinueWith((Task<IHttpActionResult> t) => 
    {
        //t.Result contains the result of the previous Task
        return t.Result; // Breakpoint #3
    });
```

Or (simpler), use a temporary value and `await`:

```
    var temp = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000); // Breakpoint #1
        return Ok(Comments); // Breakpoint #2
    });

    // Breakpoint #3
    return temp;
```

To call an `async` method without waiting for the execution to finish, just leave out the `await`. So, if you wanted to execute `GetAllComments` in parallel 5 times, you could do it like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    GetAllComments();
```

Comment: Your last statement about executing in parallel is dangerous. in Asp.Net app domains may get torn down even if background tasks are still running if there are no outstanding requests not complete yet. You must either store the tasks returned by `GetAllComments()` and do a `await Task.WhenAll(` to gauntee they finish before the request returns or queue each task up using `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(`, that does not gaurntee the task will finish but it will delay the shutdown up to a extra 90 seconds by default letting the tasks finish.

Answer (score 1):

How will Breakpoint #3 ever be hit? You've got a return before the await.

So, what will happen is that await will spawn a state machine and on completion of your thread will simply return the value.